# Does the word "signal" refer to things that already happened or that will happen?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm a bit confused about the meaning of the verb "signal". Does the word "signal" refer to things that already happened or that will happen? Here's [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/signal_2)'s take on it

> to be a sign that something exists or is likely to happen

So does it mean it can refer to both the present and the future? What does it mean?

> A fall in demand does not necessarily signal the death of the industry.

Does it mean "it's not necessarily dead" or "it won't necessarily die"? I would say sometimes the difference does matter

I started to wonder about it when writing a Javadoc for an event class. Application events typically indicate that something (already) happened so a listener to that event can do something about it

Comment: "Is likely to happen" is exactly the meaning here, but you know that from the sense rather than the grammar. If demand for a product is falling, the product must still be on sale.

Answer (score 2):

Signal can refer to future, present, or past information. It means roughly "to communicate, usually in a nonverbal way." It is perfectly correct to say that an event listener waits for a signal.

Comment: But does an event listener *signal*?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev No, the event listener *receives* the signal. You could say that the button signals the event listener or that a mouse event signals the event listener.

Comment: The person/thing that *signals* is the one sending the communication, not the one receiving it.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to ask "does an **event** signal". As I said in the original question, I was writing a Javadoc for an *event* class

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Yes, an event signals :)